# Improve efficiency loops in R for date comparison and dataset creation

Tags: r, loops, date, for-loop

I have a dataset named DateTime containing a column with ID's, a column with the start date of their visit and a column with the end date of their visit. I want to create a dataset with two column where the first one gives the date and hour of the day and the second one gives the ID that is present. So if two ID's are present at a certain hour of a certain date, this will create two lines. 
To do this I created the data frame Presence to store these to columns and made the date column of the right format. I also have a vector Dates containing all the possible dates and hours between the first start date and last end date.

I created a first for loop to check every ID over a second for loop to check every date and if there is an overlap between the dates, the data is stored in Presence. However, I have to let this run over a dataset containing 60 000 ID's and 11 000 possible dates with hour. It has now been running for over 4 hours. This doesn't really surprise me, but there must be a faster way to implement this.

```
Presence=data.frame(matrix(vector(), 5000000, 2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Presence<- data.frame(Date= Presence[,1], ID= Presence[,2])
Presence$Date<-as.POSIXct(strptime(Presence$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), tz = "Europe/Brussels")

k=1

for (i in 1:length(DateTime$ID)){
for (j in 1:length(Dates)){
   if ((DateTime$START_DATE[i]<Dates[j]) & (DateTime$END_DATE[i]>Dates[j]) ){
  Presence$Date[k]<-as.POSIXct(strptime(Dates[j], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), tz = "Europe/Brussels")
  Presence$ID[k]<-DateTime$ID[i]
  k=k+1}

}
}
```

Can someone help me with this? I'm no R expert so I might be unnecessarily going around the problem too much. Thanks!

Comment: Generally one way to speed up for loops is through using one of the ``apply`` functions (apply, lapply, mapply, vapply). These allow you to apply the same function across a whole list/matrix/vector without having to loop over them.

Comment: @Sophie Piron  Can you edit your question and include a sample of the DateTime data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation you are attempting to perform is known as an overlap join, for which the [data.table::foverlaps](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4/topics/foverlaps) function is an efficient implementation in R. The following should produce what you want:

```
library(data.table)
UniqueDates <-  unique(c(DateTime$START_DATE, DateTime$END_DATE))
Dates <- Dates[order(Dates)]
Dates <- data.frame(Date = UniqueDates, Date1 = UniqueDates, Date2 = UniqueDates)
Dates <- setDT(Dates, key = c("Date", "Dates1", "Dates2"))
DateTime <- setDT(DateTime, key=c("id", "START_DATE", "END_DATE"))
Presence <- foverlaps(Dates, DateTime, type = "within", mult = "all", nomatch = 0)
setDF(Presence)
Presence <- Presence[, c("Date", "id")]
```

You will likely need to modify the input date vector to suit your needs. Unless your available memory permits it, you may have to use the above on subsets of your input data.frame, and combine the results afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `melt` from package `reshape2`.

**First we build the data**

```
set.seed(1)
DateTime = data.frame(id = 1:10,START_DATE = Sys.Date()+ (1:10),END_DATE = Sys.Date()+ (1:10) + sample(0:10,10))

# > DateTime
#    id START_DATE   END_DATE
# 1   1 2017-07-19 2017-07-21
# 2   2 2017-07-20 2017-07-23
# 3   3 2017-07-21 2017-07-26
# 4   4 2017-07-22 2017-07-29
# 5   5 2017-07-23 2017-07-24
# 6   6 2017-07-24 2017-08-01
# 7   7 2017-07-25 2017-07-29
# 8   8 2017-07-26 2017-08-05
# 9   9 2017-07-27 2017-08-02
# 10 10 2017-07-28 2017-07-28
```

Note that last row has same date for start and end

**Then we use `melt` from package `reshape2`**

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
DateTime %>% melt(id.vars="id") %>% select(-variable) %>% unique
# id      value
# 1   1 2017-07-19
# 2   2 2017-07-20
# 3   3 2017-07-21
# 4   4 2017-07-22
# 5   5 2017-07-23
# 6   6 2017-07-24
# 7   7 2017-07-25
# 8   8 2017-07-26
# 9   9 2017-07-27
# 10 10 2017-07-28
# 11  1 2017-07-21
# 12  2 2017-07-23
# 13  3 2017-07-26
# 14  4 2017-07-29
# 15  5 2017-07-24
# 16  6 2017-08-01
# 17  7 2017-07-29
# 18  8 2017-08-05
# 19  9 2017-08-02
```

Only one row for id = 10, 2 for the others

you can also use the base function `reshape`:

```
unique(reshape(DateTime,varying = c("START_DATE","END_DATE"),direction="long",v.names = "date")[,c("id","date")])
```